# How to compute cosine similarity using two matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, cosine-similarity

I have two matrices, A (dimensions M x N) and B (N x P). In fact, they are collections of vectors - row vectors in A, column vectors in B. I want to get cosine similarity scores for every pair `a` and `b`, where `a` is a vector (row) from matrix A and `b` is a vector (column) from matrix B.

I have started by multiplying the matrices, which results in matrix `C` (dimensions M x P).

> C = A*B

However, to obtain cosine similarity scores, I need to divide each value `C(i,j)` by the norm of the two corresponding vectors. Could you suggest the easiest way to do this in Matlab?

Comment: How about http://octave.sourceforge.net/statistics/function/pdist.html ?

Comment: I took advantage of https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/pdist2.html to solve the same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution would be computing the norms first using element-wise multiplication and summation along the desired dimensions:

```
normA = sqrt(sum(A .^ 2, 2));
normB = sqrt(sum(B .^ 2, 1));
```

`normA` and `normB` are now a column vector and row vector, respectively. To divide corresponding elements in `A * B` by `normA` and `normB`, use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) like so:

```
C = bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@rdivide, A * B, normA), normB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scipy to compute it very easily.

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
cosine_sim  =  1 - sp.distance.cdist(A, B, 'cosine')
```

All you need to do is pass your 2D matrices in above formula and spicy will return you numpy array.

Refer doc here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html