# R data frame transformation

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

I have a data frame as follows, each row represents a transaction (i.e. User 001 listened to Nirvana, and also listened to Metallica, but not Slayer)

```
userid   artist      gender    country
001      nirvana     m         germany
001      metallica   m         germany
002      slayer      m         usa
003      nirvana     m         germany
003      metallica   m         germany
...      ...         ...       ...
```

Now I need to preprocess this to do item-based recommendation. I need to somehow end up with a cosine similarity matrix between the songs elements

```
             nirvana       metallica      slayer
nirvana                    0.2            0
metallica    0.24                         0
slayer       0             0
```

This is to build a recommender system and so if anyone can point me in the right direction or give me a method I would appreciate it.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340275/how-to-compute-cosine-similarity-using-two-matrices) one approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method**

The steps to do this involves:

1. Transforming the data set
2. Creating a song / song data frame
3. Calculating the cosine similarity for each cell

**Transformation**

To transform the dataset we use the plyr library to get subset where Country is Germany (I was only interested in Germany)
    library(plyr) 
    data.germany<-(data[data$country %in% "Germany",])

We then want to create a frequency table and we only want songs that users listened to

```
germany.frequency<-as.data.frame((table(data.germany$user,data.germany$artist,dnn=c("user","artist"))))

germany.frequency<-subset(germany.frequency,Freq>=1)
```

We then populate a binary matrix where 1 represents a song listened to by a user

```
germany.users <- as.matrix(unique(data.germany$user))
germany.artists <- as.matrix(unique(data.germany$artist))
holder <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(germany.users),ncol=nrow(germany.artists),dimnames=list((germany.users),(germany.artists)))
holder[,] <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(holder)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(holder)) {
    if(nrow(subset(germany.frequency, (user == rownames(holder)[i] & artist ==    colnames(holder)[j])))>0)
    {  holder[i,j]<-1 }  
  }
}

# Reorder the column names alphabetically
data.germany<-(holder[,order(colnames(holder))])
```

We now have our holder matrix read. Note: For loops take a long time in R.

**Item Based Similarity**

Drop the user column and make a new data frame

```
data.germany.ibs <- (data.germany[,!(names(data.germany) %in% c("user"))])
```

Create a helper function to calculate the cosine between two vectors

```
getCosine <- function(x,y) 
{
  this.cosine <- sum(x*y) / (sqrt(sum(x*x)) * sqrt(sum(y*y)))
  return(this.cosine)
}
```

Create a placeholder dataframe listing item vs. item

```
holder <- matrix(NA, nrow=ncol(data.germany.ibs),ncol=ncol(data.germany.ibs),dimnames=list(colnames(data.germany.ibs),colnames(data.germany.ibs)))

data.germany.ibs.similarity <- as.data.frame(holder)
```

Lets fill in those empty spaces with cosine similarities

```
for(i in 1:ncol(data.germany.ibs)) {
    for(j in 1:ncol(data.germany.ibs)) {
      data.germany.ibs.similarity[i,j]= getCosine(data.germany.ibs[i],data.germany.ibs[j])
}
```

}

Output similarity results to a file

```
write.csv(data.germany.ibs.similarity,file="final-germany-similarity.csv")
```

Get the top 10 neighbours for each

```
data.germany.neighbours <- matrix(NA, nrow=ncol(data.germany.ibs.similarity),ncol=11,dimnames=list(colnames(data.germany.ibs.similarity)))

for(i in 1:ncol(data.germany.ibs)) 
{
    data.germany.neighbours[i,] <- (t(head(n=11,rownames(data.germany.ibs.similarity[order(data.germany.ibs.similarity[,i],decreasing=TRUE),][i]))))
}
```

Output neighbour results to a file

```
  write.csv(file="final-germany-item-neighbours.csv",x=data.germany.neighbours[,-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the arules package and passing the userid and the artist.   The package has pretty clear instructions.   Quick and simple... rules generated are of a high quality.

Assuming you *need* item-based CF and nothing else will do, try Recommender Lab package.   It has prebuilt functions that may help although I've found it flaky and there's not a lot of documentation.

I find most people treat recommendation engines and collaborative filtering as synonymous when they're not at all.

Comment: I have to use both for a project ^_^

I saw recommender lab earlier, I agree it seems pretty shady. I hacked out a solution that I will put up now.